# Gronwall's inequality

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I am reading the [article](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ethanh-mai.pham-ngoc/HoangPhamRivoirardTran.pdf).
I am getting stuck with the first proof proposition 4 on page 32.
To be more specific, they understood the reason why they obtained $F(x) \le \frac{2K}{1-\frac{2R\epsilon}{\alpha}}+\frac{2CR}{\alpha -2R\epsilon}\int_{x}^{\epsilon}F(y) dy$.

Then, they choose $\epsilon$ such that $0 <\epsilon < \frac{\alpha}{2R}$ and they said that "Applying Gronwall's inequality to this inequality, we obtain

$F(x) \le \frac{K}{1-\frac{2R\epsilon}{\alpha}} \exp\left(\frac{2CR\epsilon}{\alpha - 2R\epsilon}\right)$ where $ x \in [0;\epsilon].$

I don't know which version of Gronwall's inequality did they use? Thank you for reading my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you demarcate the variables up to what you know so far?

Answer (score 2):

Because there are typographical errors in the statement here and (apparently) in the paper, and nothing is explained here about $F$ (it's *not* a CDF), let's begin by simplifying the notation.

Suppose you have a positive integrable real-valued function $F:[0, \epsilon]\to\mathbb (0,\infty)$  and for all $x\in(0,\epsilon)$ the inequality

$$F(x) \le \mu + \sigma\int_x^\epsilon F(y)\,\mathrm dy\tag{1}$$

is satisfied.  Here,  $\mu$ and $\sigma$ can be identified by inspection from (B4) in the paper,

$$\mu = \frac{K}{1 - 2R\epsilon/\alpha},\quad \sigma = \frac{2CR}{\alpha - 2R\epsilon} \gt 0.$$

**From this information alone** the paper purports to conclude that $F$ is bounded on $[0,\epsilon].$  That **this does not follow** can be established with a simple counterexample.  Take, for instance,

$$F(x) = 1/x;\quad \sigma = 1;\quad \mu = -\log\epsilon.$$

Then $(1)$ reduces to $1/x \le -\log(x),$ which always holds for $0 \lt x \le 1,$ but obviously $F$ is not bounded on $[0,\epsilon]$ no matter how small $\epsilon$ may be.

*This is not a counterexample to [Grönwall's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).* The problem here is that the order of integration in $(1)$ is the *reverse* of that required to apply the Inequality.  Changing that order would negate the integral, effectively making its multiplier $-\sigma$ negative, *and the inequality requires the multiplier be positive.*

---

Thus, Proposition (4) in the paper might be true, but it's not true for the reasons given at this part of the paper.  If I'm following the argument correctly, I think the error begins with the second line of inequalities following (B3), where "min" ought to read "max."  When the remaining lines are fixed up, a similar expression will emerge where Grönwall's Inequality *does* apply.